# PHP script can't run once i add `mysql_connect()`

Tags: php

i have installed Linux Mint 18.1, then LAMP server using the command
`sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` , for testing i tried to create a script connecting to MYSQL database, just like the following.

```
<?php
$h = "localhost";
$u = "root";
$p = "password";
$conn = mysql_connect($h,$u,$p);

echo "test";

?>
```

when i remove the line `$conn = mysql_connect($h,$u,$p);`
the script works fine, otherwise it isn't running, 
`php5.6-mysql` is already installed , and i also tried to connect using
`mysqli_connect()` instead of `mysql_connect()`
 i don't know what's wrong ?!

Comment: You're missing database name in mysql_connect()

Comment: MySQLi is not MySQL. Also, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Use MySQLi / PDO instead.

Comment: @BasuSingh 3 parameters for host , db user , db password could be enough to connect to the database server , how ever i added the database name and it also gives me the same error .

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: i have changed the display_error value to On in php.ini file, but it's not showing any errors !

Comment: can you try to add this code just before your connection?
`error_reporting(E_ALL);`
`ini_set('display_errors', 'on');`
and post the result here

Comment: well i guess the perfect solution for this is giving up using Linux Mint and returning to Fedora! thank you guys for your efforts but this version of Linux Mint really sucks!

Answer (score 0):

Paste this at the top of your file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

It will help you to see the exact error. 
Alternatively, you can try:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($h,$u,$p) or die('Connection Error');
```

If connection is not getting established then it will show **Connection Error**